# Can I view previous prices at other stations

Tags: elite-dangerous

If I have previously been to a station, is there any way that I can look up its commodity prices from another station, using the system or galaxy maps?

Eg I go to station X and buy some grain for 150 and travel to station Y

at Station Y I sell my grain for profit.  Now I would like to go back to X with some more stuff.

Is there a way (other than pencil and paper ) that I can view what the prices were in Station X when I was there (I appreciate they may have gone out of date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment there is not. Some people use pencil and paper, some use Excel spreadsheets, and some use crowdsourcing tools that rely on everybody entering info and sharing it with others. See the Elite:Dangerous forums for whatever the current iterations of these are.

Comment: The most popular seems to be: http://www.elitetradingtool.co.uk/ (which also includes great tools for finding nearby high-profit trading loops)

Answer (score -1):

No it´s not. Like the old Elite title :-)  New is, you can see your profit each unit and the galactic average price, then you decide by yourself if its worth or not.

Comment: It does provide an answer, "No". It's not clear, or adding to the previous answer -- but it's an answer.